# Anyway to Parallel Yield c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, parallel-processing

I have multiple enumerators that enumerate over flat files. I originally had each enumerator in a Parallel Invoke and each Action was adding to a `BlockingCollection<Entity>` and that collections was returning a ConsumingEnumerable();

```
public interface IFlatFileQuery
{
    IEnumerable<Entity> Run();
}

public class FlatFile1 : IFlatFileQuery
{
    public IEnumerable<Entity> Run()
    {
        // loop over a flat file and yield each result
        yield return Entity;
    }
} 

public class Main
{
    public IEnumerable<Entity> DoLongTask(ICollection<IFlatFileQuery> _flatFileQueries)
    {
            // do some other stuff that needs to be returned first:
            yield return Entity;

            // then enumerate and return the flat file data
        foreach (var entity in GetData(_flatFileQueries))
        {
            yield return entity;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Entity> GetData(_flatFileQueries)
    {
        var buffer = new BlockingCollection<Entity>(100);

        var actions = _flatFileQueries.Select(fundFileQuery => (Action)(() =>
        {
            foreach (var entity in fundFileQuery.Run())
            {
                buffer.TryAdd(entity, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
        })).ToArray();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Parallel.Invoke(actions);

            buffer.CompleteAdding();
        });

        return buffer.GetConsumingEnumerable();
    }
}
```

However after a bit of testing it turns out that the code change below is about 20-25% faster.

```
private IEnumerable<Entity> GetData(_flatFileQueries)
{
    return _flatFileQueries.AsParallel().SelectMany(ffq => ffq.Run());
}
```

The trouble with the code change is that it waits till all flat file queries are enumerated before it returns the whole lot that can then be enumerated and yielded.

Would it be possible to yield in the above bit of code somehow to make it even faster?

I should add that at most the combined results of all the flat file queries might only be 1000 or so Entities.

**Edit**:
Changing it to the below doesn't make a difference to the run time. (R# even suggests to go back to the way it was)

```
private IEnumerable<Entity> GetData(_flatFileQueries)
{
        foreach (var entity in _flatFileQueries.AsParallel().SelectMany(ffq => ffq.Run()))
        {
            yield return entity;
        }
}
```

Comment: `"The trouble with the code change is that it waits till all flat file queries are enumerated before it returns the whole lot that can then be enumerated and yielded."` What's your basis for that assumption?  Have you actually tested it and verified that?  I wouldn't expect it to be the case at all.

Comment: @Sevy tbh that was just an assumption. Will try and experiment now.

Comment: `LINQ`, as a rule, is quite good at deferring execution as much as possible.  I would be very, very surprised if it didn't do so here, although I'm less familiar with PLINQ than traditional LINQ.

Comment: @Sevy see my Edit, it doesn't make it faster.

Comment: I never said it would.  Obviously your "change" adds overhead and no additional value.  My Point is that `SelectMany`, underneath, is implemented using deferred execution.  It doesn't return the results of the query it returns the query itself, so you can just return it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The trouble with the code change is that it waits till all flat file queries are enumerated before it returns the whole lot that can then be enumerated and yielded.

Let's prove that it's false by a simple example. First, let's create a `TestQuery` class that will yield a single entity after a given time. Second, let's execute several test queries in parallel and measure how long it took to yield their result.

```
public class TestQuery : IFlatFileQuery {

    private readonly int _sleepTime;

    public IEnumerable<Entity> Run() {
        Thread.Sleep(_sleepTime);
        return new[] { new Entity() };
    }

    public TestQuery(int sleepTime) {
        _sleepTime = sleepTime;
    }

}

internal static class Program {

    private static void Main() {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var queries = new IFlatFileQuery[] {
            new TestQuery(2000),
            new TestQuery(3000),
            new TestQuery(1000)
        };
        foreach (var entity in queries.AsParallel().SelectMany(ffq => ffq.Run()))
            Console.WriteLine("Yielded after {0:N0} seconds", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

This code prints:

> Yielded after 1 seconds
>   Yielded after 2 seconds
>   Yielded after 3 seconds

You can see with this output that `AsParallel()` will yield each result as soon as its available, so everything works fine. Note that you might get different timings depending on the degree of parallelism (such as "2s, 5s, 6s" with a degree of parallelism of 1, effectively making the whole operation not parallel at all). This output comes from an 4-cores machine.

Your long processing will probably scale with the number of cores, if there is no common bottleneck between the threads (such as a shared locked resource). You might want to profile your algorithm to see if there are slow parts that can be improved using tools such as [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/).

Comment: This is good work, but what is the reason for the difference in performance which the OP observed?

Comment: @usr, that I didn't investigate, and your answer seems very good on this point. The OP was under the assumption that `AsParallel()` wasn't yielding and asked for improvement in this area, which is what I answered to.

Comment: Yielding only 3 results doesn't count as a robust experiment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a red flag in your code anywhere. There are no outrageous inefficiencies. I think it comes down to multiple smaller differences.

PLINQ is very good at processing streams of data. Internally, it works more efficiently than adding items to a synchronized list one-by-one. I suspect that your calls to `TryAdd` are a bottleneck because each call requires at least two `Interlocked` operations internally. Those can put enormous load on the inter-processor memory bus because all threads will compete for the same cache line.

PLINQ is cheaper because internally, it does some buffering. I'm sure it doesn't output items one-by-one. Probably it batches them and amortizes sycnhronization cost that way over multiple items.

A second issue would be the bounded capacity of the `BlockingCollection`. 100 is not a lot. This might lead to a lot of waiting. Waiting is costly because it requires a call to the kernel and a context switch.

Answer (score 2):

I make this alternative that works good for me in any scenario:

This works for me:

- In a Task in a Parallel.Foreach Enqueue in a ConcurrentQueue the item
  transformed to be processed.
- The task has a continue that marks a
  flag with that task ends.
- In the same thread of execution with tasks
  ends a while dequeue and yields

Fast and excellent results for me:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew (() =>
{
    Parallel.ForEach<string> (TextHelper.ReadLines(FileName), ProcessHelper.DefaultParallelOptions,
    (string currentLine) =>
    {
        // Read line, validate and enqeue to an instance of FileLineData (custom class)
    });
}).
ContinueWith 
(
    ic => isCompleted = true 
);


while (!isCompleted || qlines.Count > 0)
{
    if (qlines.TryDequeue (out returnLine))
    {
        yield return returnLine;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the [`ParallelQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelquery) class, when is working on `IEnumerable<T>` sources, employs a partitioning strategy known as "chunk partitioning". With this strategy each worker thread grabs a progressively larger number of items each time. This means that it has an input buffer. Then the results are accumulated into an output buffer, having a size chosen by the system, before they are available to the consumer of the query. You can disable both buffers by using the configuration options [`EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.enumerablepartitioneroptions) and [`ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelmergeoptions).

```
private IEnumerable<Entity> GetData(ICollection<IFlatFileQuery> flatFileQueries)
{
    return Partitioner
        .Create(flatFileQueries, EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering)
        .AsParallel()
        .AsOrdered()
        .WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)
        .SelectMany(ffq => ffq.Run());
}
```

This way each worker thread will grab only one item at a time, and will propagate the result as soon as it is computed.

> **NoBuffering:** Create a partitioner that takes items from the source enumerable one at a time and does not use intermediate storage that can be accessed more efficiently by multiple threads. This option provides support for low latency (items will be processed as soon as they are available from the source) and provides partial support for dependencies between items (a thread cannot deadlock waiting for an item that the thread itself is responsible for processing).

> **NotBuffered:** Use a merge without output buffers. As soon as result elements have been computed, make that element available to the consumer of the query.