# parallel foreach with yield statements

Tags: c#, collections, foreach, yield-return, parallel.foreach

I had a quick question in c#. Is there a way to have yield statements in a Parallel.ForEach loop? I saw that yield statements are not allowed in anonymous methods, but is there an alternative way in c# to achieve the same functionality, of have "yield return" statements returning elements of a collection in the body of a parallel foreach loop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806240/how-to-yield-from-parallel-tasks-in-net-4-5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381897/anyway-to-parallel-yield-c-sharp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021779/thread-safety-of-yield-return-with-parallel-foreach  and many many others, not only on SO. Is it so hard to type three words "c# parallel yield" into google?

Comment: Have you check this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412879/parallel-foreach-yield-return?rq=1